# How to count the number and % occurrence of a value in a column only for specific rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

For example if my data looks something like this:

```
Group   Smoker
1       Ex
1       None
1       None
2       Current
1       Current
2       Ex
2       None
```

I want to calculate the % or number of Ex, none and current smokers in Group 1 and the % or number of ex, none and current smokers in group 2

Is there a simple code to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package to calculate the count and percentage.

```
library(dplyr)

# Count
dat2 <- dat %>%
  count(Group, Smoker)

dat2
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#   Group Smoker      n
#   <int> <chr>   <int>
# 1     1 Current     1
# 2     1 Ex          1
# 3     1 None        2
# 4     2 Current     1
# 5     2 Ex          1
# 6     2 None        1

# Percentage
dat3 <- dat2 %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(Percent = n/ sum(n) * 100) %>%
  ungroup()

dat3
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
#   Group Smoker      n Percent
#   <int> <chr>   <int>   <dbl>
# 1     1 Current     1    25.0
# 2     1 Ex          1    25.0
# 3     1 None        2    50.0
# 4     2 Current     1    33.3
# 5     2 Ex          1    33.3
# 6     2 None        1    33.3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Group   Smoker
1       Ex
                  1       None
                  1       None
                  2       Current
                  1       Current
                  2       Ex
                  2       None",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! but when I apply the first code I get the error message : Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Ex' not found. do you know why this could be?

Comment: @A.A Did you load the `dplyr` package?